# Bouncing Bubble Algorithm for smallest enclosing sphere

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, 3d, geometry, point-clouds

I am interested in the [Bouncing Bubble Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere#Bouncing_Bubble) to find the approximate smallest enclosing sphere for a set of points.

I understand the basic concept: "*each time a point outside the ball is found, the ball will be moved towards it and increase the radius at the same time. The growth in each step is designed so that it will not exceed the optimum radius, thus the radius is getting closer and closer to the optimum.*"
[image]

I have however been unable to find anything more specific about it anywhere online. How is the growth calculated? How far is the shift towards the new point?

I am looking for either an example implementation or enough information to implement my own solution.

Comment: from the wikipedia link it looks like it was published in 2012 by Bo Tian. I couldn't find an institution/research page, but if you can find/contact the author or find a free version that would explain it (here is the paid version: http://www.grin.com/en/e-book/204869/bouncing-bubble-a-fast-algorithm-for-minimal-enclosing-ball-problem)

Comment: This algorithm appears to be neither peer-reviewed nor O(n) in fixed dimension. You could try asking also Timothy Bo Field, the Wikipedia editor who [contributed the writeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bounding_sphere&oldid=525914976).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not realize that the whole wikipedia article section could be attributed to a single author (who apparently also has a  suspiciously similar name as the author of the paper?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realize this post is a year old, but I implemented the bouncing bubble algorithm in C++ and thought maybe some people would find it useful. This is based on the paper by Tian Bo, which I purchased for $18.

```
BoundSphere calculateBoundSphere(vector<Vertex> vertices){
    Vector3D center = vertices[0].position;
    float radius = 0.0001f;
    Vector3D pos, diff;
    float len, alpha, alphaSq;
    vector<Vertex>::iterator it;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++){
            pos = it->position;
            diff = pos - center;
            len = diff.length();
            if (len > radius){
                alpha = len / radius;
                alphaSq = alpha * alpha;
                radius = 0.5f * (alpha + 1 / alpha) * radius;
                center = 0.5f * ((1 + 1 / alphaSq) * center + (1 - 1 / alphaSq) * pos);
            }
        }
    }

    for (it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++){
        pos = it->position;
        diff = pos - center;
        len = diff.length();
        if (len > radius){
            radius = (radius + len) / 2.0f;
            center = center + ((len - radius) / len * diff);
        }
    }

    return BoundSphere(center, radius);
}
```

Comment: Closure at last, thanks! I tried out the algorithm; in my entirely unscientific tests it seems to perform about twice as fast as [Ritter's approximation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere#Ritter.27s_bounding_sphere), but produces much more wasteful approximations. The results get better if I choose the average of all vertices as start value instead of the first point, but the produced spheres are still significantly larger than the optimum, so I'll probably stick with Ritter for now

Comment: Actually, the mentioned large errors were due to a transcription error on my part. With that corrected, the results seem to be slightly better than Ritter's approximation in addition to being faster, thought I am having some trouble understanding why it works. Could you add the expected maximum error and perhaps some description of the two steps to the algorithm? In particular, why is the first step repeated exactly two times?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/hbf/miniball) is the implementation you asked for. For analysis part, you can get the idea reading the following.

These anaylsis are for circle(2d) but the extension to sphere(3d) should be easy. I am sure the analysis will help.

### **An O(n2)-time Algorithm**

- Draw a circle at center, c, such that points of given set lie within
  the circle. Clearly, this circle can be made smaller (or else we
  have the solution).
- Make a circle smaller by finding the point A farthest from the
  center of circler, and drawing a new circle with the same center and
  passing through the point A. These two steps produce a smaller
  enclosing circle. The reason that the new circle is smaller is that
  this new circle still contains all the points of given set, except
  now it passes through farthest point, x, rather than enclosing it.
- If the circle passes through 2 or more points, proceed to step 4.
  Otherwise, make the circle smaller by moving the center towards
  point A, until the circle makes contact with another point B from
  the set.
- At this stage, we a circle, C, that passes through two or more
  points of a given set. If the circle contains an interval
  (point-free interval) of arc greater than half the circle's
  circumference on which no points lie, the circle can be made
  smaller. Let D and E be the points at the ends of this point-free
  interval. While keeping D and E on the circle's boundary, reduce the
  diameter of the circle until we have either case (a) or case (b).

  - Case (a)   The diameter is the distance DE.
    We are done!
  - Case (b)   The circle C touches another point from the set, F.
    Check whether there exits point-free arc intervals of  length more than half the circumference of C.
    IF
    no such point-free arc intervals exit THEN
    We are done!
    Else
    Goto step 4.
    In this case, three points must lie on an arc less than half the circumference in length. We repeat step 4 on the outer  two of the three points on the arc.

Analysis

This algorithm is straight forward, but expensive to implement. Step 1, 2 and 3 require linear time in the number of points in the given set. In step 4 above, it takes linear time to find each new point F. However, finding the point F does not guarantee the termination of the algorithm. Step 4 must be repeated until the circle contains no point-free interval longer than half its circumference. In the worst case, this requires (n-2) iterations of step 4, implying that the total time spent in step 4 could be on the order of the square of the size of the point set.

Hence, this algorithm is O(n2).

---

### **O(n) Algorithm**

Nimrod Megiddo proposes the algorithm and it uses the prune-and-search techniques for linear programming to find the minimal enclosing circle in O(n) time.

Prune-and-Search

The essence of Megiddo's algorithm is prune-and-search. In a prune-and-search algorithm, a linear amount of work is done at each step to reduce the input size by a constant fraction f. If this can be achieved, then the total amount of work done will reduce to O(n)*(1 + (1-f) + (1-f)2 + ...). In this formula, the infinite series is geometric and sums to a constant value, and so the total running time is O(n).

For example, suppose that by inspecting our set of n input elements we can discard 1/4 of them as irrelevant to the solution. By repeatedly applying this inspection to the remaining elements, we can reduce the input to a size which is trivial to solve, say n≤3. The total time taken to achieve this reduction will be proportional to (n + 3n/4 + 9n/16 + ...). It is easy to show that this series approaches, and never exceeds, a limit of 4n. Therefore, the total running time is proportional to n, as required.

The idea of using the geometric series to reduce an algorithm to linear time predates Megiddo's work; in particular, it had previously been used to develop O(n) median-finding algorithms. However, he was the first to apply it to a number of fundamental problems in computational geometry.

Megiddo's Linear-Time Algorithm

To find the minimal enclosing circle (MEC) of a set of points, Megiddo's algorithm discards at least n/16 points at each (linear-time) iteration. That is, given a set S of n points, the algorithm identifies n/16 points that can be removed from S without affecting the MEC of S. This procedure can be repeatedly applied until some trivial base case is reached (such as n=3), with the total running time proportional to (n + 15n/16 + 225n/256 + ...) = 16n.

In order to find n/16 points to discard, a great deal of cleverness is required. The algorithm makes heavy use of two subroutines:

- median(S, >):   Takes a set S of elements and a metric for comparing
  them pairwise, and returns the median of the elements.
- MEC-center(S, L):   Takes a set S of points and a line L, and
  determines which side of L the center of the MEC of S lies on.

As mentioned above, median() predates Megiddo's work, whereas the algorithm described here as MEC-center() was presented as part of his 1983 paper. To explore these procedures in detail would go beyond the scope of this outline, but each uses prune-and-search to run in linear time. The algorithm used by MEC-center() amounts to a simplified version of the algorithm as a whole.

Given these primitives, the algorithm for discarding n/16 input points runs as follows:

- Arbitrarily pair up the n points in S to get n/2 pairs.
- Construct a bisecting line for each pair of points, to get n/2
  bisectors in total.
- Call median() to find the bisector with median slope. Call this slope
  mmid.
- Pair up each bisector of slope ≥ mmid with another of slope < mmid,
  to get n/4 intersection points. Call the set of these points I.
- Call median() to find the point in I with median y-value. Call this
  y-value ymid.
- Call MEC-center() to find which side of the line y=ymid the
  MEC-center C lies on.   (Without loss of generality, suppose it lies
  above.)
- Let I' be the subset of points of I whose y-values are less than
  ymid. (I' contains n/8 points.)
- Find a line L with slope mmid such that half the points in I' lie to
  L's left, half to its right.
- Call MEC-center() on L. Without loss of generality, suppose C lies on
  L's right.
- Let I'' be the subset of I' whose points lie to the left of L. (I''
  contains n/16 points.)

We can now discard one point in S for each of the n/16 intersection points in I''. The reasoning runs as follows. After  two calls to MEC-center(), we have found that the MEC-center C must lie above ymid and to the right of L, whereas any point in I'' is below ymid and to the left of L.

Each point in I'' is at the meeting point of two bisector lines. One of these bisectors must have slope ≥ mmid, and therefore must never pass through the quadrant where we know C to lie. Call this bisector B. Now, we know which side of B C lies on, so of the two points whose bisector is B, let PC be the one that lies on the same side as C, and let the other be PX.

It is easy to show that PC must be nearer to C than PX. It follows that PC cannot lie on the minimal enclosing circle, and thus we can safely discard a point PC for each of the n/16 intersection points in I''.

We have not discussed here how this algorithm can be made to deal with degenerate input (parallel bisectors, collinear points, etc), but it turns out that we get the same performance guarantees for such cases. The fact of the matter is for degenerate input the algorithm is able to discard more than n/16 points. In short, Megiddo's algorithm guarantees to prune at least n/16 points in each iteration independent to input.

Therefore, by the argument based on the geometric series, Megiddo's algorithm computes the minimal enclosing circle in linear time.

Refer to [this](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rfink1/skew/papers/MegiddoLinearAlgsforProgrammingInR3.pdf) paper for more on the O(n) Algorithm

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I am particularly interested in the Bouncing Bubble algorithm. I know that there are exact algorithms for bounding spheres that are just as efficient, but that particular algorithm sounded elegant and interesting, and easy to modify for special cases. I however begin to wonder that I may have been mislead by the wikipedia description, which I suspect may have been written by the author of the algorithm or an associate.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Upon closer review of the animation and the Wikipedia article, I've decided my algorithm is not Bouncing Bubble. From the animation it is clear that Bouncing Bubble moves the bounding sphere, while my algorithm only grows it in one direction at a time. Also, my understanding is that Bouncing Bubble uses an approximation and may not contain all the points; however, there seems to be a tolerance parameter that you can control.

I think my algorithm still has some nice properties:

1. It's O(n).
2. It's incremental.
3. It's guaranteed to contain all the points.
4. It's dead simple. The only thing simpler would be to find the axis-aligned bounding box, and then put a sphere around that, but that's surely going to be a larger volume than this algorithm produces.

---

I came up with a O(n) incremental algorithm on my own, which from the description on Wikipedia I believe must be the Bouncing Bubble algorithm. I have no idea how close it comes to the minimally bounding circle. First I'll try to explain my reasoning behind the algorithm. It may help to draw this on paper.

Imagine you have a bounding circle with some center *C* and radius *r*. You want to extend the circle to contain a new point *P*. You compute the distance *d* from *C* to *P* and find that it is greater than *r*, so it must be outside the circle. Now if you cast a ray from *P* through *C*, it exits the back of the circle at *A*.

Now imagine you pin the circle down at *A* and then expand it along the ray back toward *P*. It will continue to contain all the previous points, and now it contains *P*. The diameter of this new circle is *r + d*, thus its radius is *r' = (r + d) / 2*. Walk along the ray from *P* to *A* by the distance of the new radius, and you're at the center of the new circle.

Here's a sketch of the algorithm:

1. Initialize the bounding sphere to be centered on the first point *C* with a radius *r* of 0.
2. For each remaining point *P*:

   1. If the distance *d* from *P* to *C* is *<= r*, skip it.
   2. If *d > r*:

      1. The new radius *r' = (r + d) / 2*.
      2. The new center *C' = P + r' (C - P) / d*.

And here's some Objective-C code I wrote just today:

```
- (void)updateBoundingVolume {
    self.boundingSphereCenter = GLKVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
    self.boundingSphereRadius = 0;

    GLfloat* vertex = self.vertices;
    GLfloat* endV = vertex + 3 * self.vertNum;

    if (vertex < endV) {
        // initialize to zero radius sphere centered on the first point
        self.boundingSphereCenter = GLKVector3Make(vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2]);
        vertex += 3;
    }

    while (vertex < endV) {
        GLKVector3 p = GLKVector3Make(vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2]);
        vertex += 3;

        float d = GLKVector3Distance(self.boundingSphereCenter, p);
        if (d <= self.boundingSphereRadius) {
            // already inside the sphere
            continue;
        }

        // length of line from other side of sphere through the center to the new point
        // divide by 2 for radius
        self.boundingSphereRadius = (self.boundingSphereRadius + d) / 2;

        // unit vector from new point to old center
        GLKVector3 u = GLKVector3DivideScalar(GLKVector3Subtract(self.boundingSphereCenter, p), d);
        // step back from the new point by the new radius to get the new center
        self.boundingSphereCenter = GLKVector3Add(p, GLKVector3MultiplyScalar(u, self.boundingSphereRadius));
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested your code and the results are not very convincing. In my test cases, your bounding sphere was about 10% larger than the one centered at the bounding box of the data (which is also not the optimal one). Nevertheless, thanks for sharing your code!